# What is the best way to import selective properties from JSON into a sql server table

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a json file which contains data I need to import into a table, the problem is I only want the `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `preferredGazzeteerName` properties.

Here is how my json data looks like :

```
[
  {
    "MRGID": 2375,
    "gazetteerSource": "Nomenclature des espaces maritimes/List of maritime areas",
    "placeType": "Strait",
    "latitude": 51.036666666667,
    "longitude": 1.5486111111111,
    "minLatitude": 49.71788333,
    "minLongitude": 0.238905863,
    "maxLatitude": 51.78156033,
    "maxLongitude": 2.744909289,
    "precision": 21000,
    "preferredGazetteerName": "Dover Strait",
    "preferredGazetteerNameLang": "English",
    "status": "standard",
    "accepted": 2375
  },
  {
    "MRGID": 2376,
    "gazetteerSource": "The Times comprehensive atlas of the world. 10th ed. Times Books: London, UK. ISBN 0-7230-0792-6. 67, 220, 124 plates pp.,",
    "placeType": "Strait",
    "latitude": 54.604722222222,
    "longitude": 11.220833333333,
    "minLatitude": null,
    "minLongitude": null,
    "maxLatitude": null,
    "maxLongitude": null,
    "precision": 40000,
    "preferredGazetteerName": "Femer Baelt",
    "preferredGazetteerNameLang": "English",
    "status": "standard",
    "accepted": 2376
  }]
```

and table [image]

The `preferredGazetteerName` values will be inserted at strait name column.

Comment: Great. Can you share the code you wrote to solve this issue?

Comment: @dfundako Can we do it in ssms directly.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and up allows for JSON operations.

Comment: The data import/export wizards in SSMS have no support for JSON. You'll have to write a query regardless. Fortunately that's simple enough: `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (preferredGazetteerName NVARCHAR(50), latitude DECIMAL(12,7), longitude DECIMAL(12,7))`. Turning that into an `INSERT` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I am using sql server 2012. Do I have to do it like c# objects -> procedure -> insert then?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I have read about `OPENJSON` , will try.

Comment: That's one way. But if you have a recent version of VS, you already have a SQL Server 2016 LocalDB installed as `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. Importing the JSON there and then using the regular bulk import/export to export to SQL Server 2012 is another option. If this is not a one-off, you're looking at writing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach where we split the JSON string with a delimiter of `'{'`  then it just becomes a matter of string manipulation

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) ='... your JSON String ...'

Select Name = left(Name,charindex(',',Name+',')-1)
      ,Lat  = try_convert(float,left(Lat,charindex(',',Lat+',')-1))
      ,Lng  = try_convert(float,left(Lng,charindex(',',Lng+',')-1))
 From  (
        Select Name = ltrim(replace(substring(RetVal,nullif(charindex('"preferredGazetteerName"',RetVal),0)+25,75),'"',''))
              ,Lat  = ltrim(substring(RetVal,nullif(charindex('"latitude"',RetVal),0) +11,25))
              ,Lng  = ltrim(substring(RetVal,nullif(charindex('"longitude"',RetVal),0)+12,25))
         From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](@S,'{') 
       ) A
 Where Name is not null
```

**Returns**

```
Name            Lat               Lng
Dover Strait    51.036666666667   1.5486111111111
Femer Baelt     54.604722222222   11.220833333333
```

**The Split/Parse TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

Comment: It's a good idea to mention that this will work only for "trivial" JSON (as posted in the question); things will fail badly (yet silently) when objects contain other objects as properties. Worse, it fails even on simpler cases where one of the properties we're searching after is lexically the last one in the object (and hence not terminated with `,`), although that's probably fixable. In other words, this is not usable as a general JSON parser (which should not come as a surprise, but still).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Correct, it is not solution for variable depth or nested JSON.   This is a single purpose solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is an unconventional way but that was good enough for me since it was only a one time operation without nested objects and I didnt wanted to write c# code which was never gonna reused. So thank you for that.